# graph theory,problem of graph

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if dichotomy graph $(X,Y,E)$ is $k$-regular , where $k\geqslant 1 \Rightarrow |X|=|Y|$.

Please help me

Comment: Any initial thoughts? Any attempt that shows us where you are stuck?

Comment: By dichotomy graph, I assume you mean bipartite graph.

Comment: yeaa exactly , i have no idea , the truth is that k|X| = k|Y|  but what next?

Answer (score 2):

We can use the double counting argument - if we count the size of a collection (the number of edges in this case) in two different ways, then the two values we get must be equal to each other.

If $G$ is a bipartite graph with bipartition $(X,Y)$, then the number of edges incident to vertices in $X$ must equal the number of edges incident to vertices in $Y$ (which must equal the number of edges in $G$).  If $G$ is also $k$-regular, we get $|X|~k = |Y|~k = |E(G)|$.

Comment: yeeaaa good solution thank a lot , what are u studying ? i am student of Applied Mathematics in AGH : )